# Square-Rooting in Javascript calculator not showing up

Tags: javascript, calculator

I have been making a javascript calculator for a while and I can get all basic functions and the pow() function but I can't get it to do the Math.sqrt() function.  I've had this problem for the past few days.  Here's my code, thanks in advance:

```
function calc()
{
    var D = "";
    var A = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("op").value;
    var C = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    X = parseInt(A);
    S = 2
    var Z = "If you're seeing this, that means that the code isn't working!!"
    D = eval(A + B + C);
    if (B == "%")
    {
        D = ""
        Z = Math.sqrt(X)*1
    }
    else if (B == "^")
    {
        D = ""
        Z = Math.pow(X, C)
    }
    else if (B == "^2")
    {
        D = ""
        Z = Math.pow(X, S)
    }
    else if (B == "")
    {
        D = "No Operator"
        Z = ""
    }
    document.getElementById("result").value = D;
    document.getElementById("sqrt-result").value = Z;       
    return false;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to follow with the variable names you're using - is this minimised code? Where's the original?

Comment: This is all of the Javascript used for the calculator function, it is not minimized at all... I have so many variables from previous tries at fixing the code...  Sorry I forget to do some things while editing my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested it and your code is working fine. My assumption is that you are trying to use the square root functionality and not putting anything in `num2`, which would seem natural for calculating the square root of a number. However, if you open your error console, you would notice that `eval` doesn't like it when you try to evaluate something with nothing after an operator. My suggestion would be to move the `eval` below the `if`s so that it's only used if it needs to be.

```
function calc()
{
    var D = "";
    var A = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("op").value;
    var C = document.getElementById("num2").value;
    X = parseInt(A);
    S = 2
    var Z = "If you're seeing this, that means that the code isn't working!!"
    if (B == "%")
    {
        Z = Math.sqrt(X)*1
    }
    else if (B == "^")
    {
        Z = Math.pow(X, C)
    }
    else if (B == "^2")
    {
        Z = Math.pow(X, S)
    }
    else if (B == "")
    {
        D = "No Operator"
        Z = ""
    } else {
        // Only do this if not doing any of the above calculations
        D = eval(A + B + C);
    }
    document.getElementById("result").value = D;
    document.getElementById("sqrt-result").value = Z;       
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I guess Dreamweaver CS4 was having a problem with the code.